# Regex help. I need ideas for solve the String Calculator kata with Groovy

Tags: regex, groovy

I'm working on [**String Calculator code kata**](http://www.osherove.com/tdd-kata-1/) with Groovy.

There are a lot of scenarios that solve for achieve the solution:

I have:

```
//;\n1;2;3
//#\n1#2#3
//+\n1+2+3
//*\n1*2*3
//?\n1?2?3
```

I want:

```
1,2,3
```

My implementation:

```
String numbers = "//;\n1;2;3"

numbers.find(/\/\/\S[\n]/) { match ->
    def delimeter = match[2]
    numbers = numbers.minus(match).replaceAll(delimeter, ",")
}
```

With this solution **I solved the first and second expressions, but I don't know how solve the others expressions**.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
```

The problem is that we must also consider any symbol that match with the sintaxt of regular expressions like `+`, `*` or `?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have the solution:

```
String numbers = "//+\n1+2+3"

numbers.find(/(?s)\/\/(.*)\n/) { match ->
    def delimeter = match[1]  // also match[0][2]
    numbers = numbers.minus(match[0]).replace(delimeter, ",")
}
```

An important point (?s):

In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.
Dotall mode can also be enabled via the embedded flag expression (?s)

**But really the problem was here**: `.replace(delimeter, ",")`

Answer (score 0):

```
//(.)\n(\d)\1(\d)\1(\d)
```

Need to use links.
(.) - math thiw any character, and \1 - math thiw character on it\

For next example you can apply this: `//\[(.*?)\]\\n(\d)\1(\d)\1(\d)`
It math thiw

> //[***]\n1***2***3

And last: `//\[(.*?)\]\[(.*?)\]\\n(\d)\1(\d)\2(\d)`

> //[**][%%]\n1**2%%3

And finaly:

```
//\[(.*?)\](?:\[(.*?)\])?\\n(\d)\1(\d)(?:\2|\1)(\d)
```

I think it's can work ewerythere
P.S : (\d) you can replace what you want. I think you need (\d*)

Comment: I think haven't expressed well. I only need a pattern that match with `//any_thing_include_for_example_+_or_*\n`